# Resetting a function, or perhaps stopping something and starting it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var number = 10;
    var offset = 10;
    var page_number = 2;    

    /* Bind the scroll function to an event */
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {

        /* If the scroll height plus the window height is 
           more than the document height minus 10, continue */
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > 
           $(document).height() - 10) {         

            /* Quick message so you know more stuff is loading */
            $('.loading-more').html('Keep scrolling for more posts to load..');     

            $.post('<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
                action: 'and_action',
                off: offset+number,
                pagenumber: page_number - 1
                }, function(data) {
                    offset = offset+number;                         
                    $('.empty-div').append('<p><strong>Page '+page_number+'</strong></p><br />'+data);
                    page_number += 1;               
                    $(this).unbind(e);                                          
            }); 
        }       
    });
});
```

This checks if the user is near the bottom of the page and loads more content. The problem is if the user scrolls slowly near the critical point, or scrolls up and down over and over again really fast, the `$.post` function runs a few times, meaning you end up with a few instances of the data I'm loading.

What I had tried doing was binding and unbinding the `e` variable, but it didn't work so good. Is there anyway to perhaps run the `post` function once, and then have the function reset so when the user scrolls down again it will run again, so more than one instance of the data doesn't load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just set a boolean as a representation of the current state: loading/ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var busy = false;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function (e) {
        if( !busy && goodposition){

           // load more
           busy = true;

           $.post(..., function(date){
             busy = false;
           });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why not do something like this:

```
var doingWork = false;

if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10) 
    && !doingWork) 
{
    doingWork = true;
```

then reset `doingWork` to `false` once you need the functionality back

Answer (score 0):

Two answers have suggested doing this by setting a boolean to note whether a request exists.  This is probably the route I'd take.  The other option is to cancel the existing request.

[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) returns an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) object.  This means that you can cache the request object and use the `.abort()` method to cancel an ongoing request:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > 
        $(document).height() - 10) {         

        $('.loading-more').html('Keep scrolling for more posts to load..');     

        if (curxhr && (curxhr.readyState != 4) { // if the curxhr object exists and has not completed
            curxhr.abort(); // abort the request
        }

        curxhr = $.post('<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
            action: 'and_action',
            off: offset+number,
            pagenumber: page_number - 1
            }, function(data) {
                // snip                                      
        }); 
    }       
});
```